# How to keep user notified that application is running in background?

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5, ios4

Since few days i am searching for the functionality which will allow me keep user posted that application is running in background. I have attached a !image for what exactly i am looking for. i tried googling but could not get exactly what I need. when i tap on the flashing red bar it takes me back to the application.

Thanks in advance.

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The red banner you pictured is provided by the system, is shown only if your application uses background audio recording (see `AVAudioSession`), and doesn't provide the opportunity for you to choose what happens when the user taps it.

Unless your app fits into one of a [few specific classes](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iPhone/Conceptual/iPhoneOSProgrammingGuide/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow/ManagingYourApplicationsFlow.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40007072-CH4-SW20), it doesn't actually "run" while in the background. Instead, it's "suspended" -- still in memory, but gets no CPU time. What happens outside of your app is thus up to the system, not to you... the only way to show a banner that will launch your application is to use a push notification service or `UILocalNotification`, but those banners are only shown briefly, and you don't get to control their duration. What you seem to be specifically asking for isn't possible using public API.

Answer (score 0):

The kind of notification you want isn't supported by the current iOS for third-party developers.

Answer (score 0):

If you want that kind of functionality then implement Apple Push Notification service through

this you can first give message to Apple push notification service. then Apple service

automatically generate notification for your App as you want.

Comment: Thanks, however i think push notification will show badge on my application. i haven't tried but it will not flash red bar continuously when my application is in background. I will definitely try this option.

Comment: No, I think It continuously show red bar untill your App is in background & also generate a type of alert for you that show your App name with message that you want to give it...